# Jquery sort divs by value ascending / descending on click

Tags: jquery, sorting

So I have some divs with text values, and others with numerical values, they're sorted out like this:

```
<div id="Test1">
        <div class="likelyOddHeader">
            <div class="likelyOddA">Test1</div>
            <div class="likelyOddB"><img src="img here"/></div>
            <div class="timeZone">West</div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
                <div class="weight">127</div>
                <div class="values">Value5: Value here. <br />
                                                DbValue5: 1234, DbValue6, 123456</div>
                <div class="overrides">Overrides: 0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Test2">
        <div class="likelyEvenHeader">
            <div class="likelyEvenA">Test2</div>
                            <div class="img here"/></div>
            <div class="timeZone">East</div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
                <div class="weight">124</div>
                <div class="values">  Value5: Value here. <br />
                                    DbValue5: 1234, DbValue6, 123456</div>
                <div class="overrides">Overrides: 0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was hoping to sort by weight, name, and perhaps timezone name.   Could someone help me out with this?